# set size of gallery android

Tags: android, gallery

I have a problem with a set size of a gallery in android. I want to set size of gallery (like half of screen of device) I am using this code:

```
int width = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_height);
int height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_width);
iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(width, height));
iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(30, 40)); `
```

and main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mySelection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20px"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/myGallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="bottom" 
         android:spacing="
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.46" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

Also, setting depth and height in `images.xml` file is not working.

Answer (score 0):

ur height is not working coz u didnt give the value..see ur code again.. and for setting size of gridview use this code:

```
Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int halfDeviceWidth = display.getWidth()/2;
    int halfDeviceHeight = display.getHeight()/2;
iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(halfDeviceWidth, halfDeviceHeight));
```

use this code..

Comment: where i have to give value... i dont understand... please give some explanation...thanks you.....

Comment: the code u have written delete that and put this code. u should ppt that in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of ur `activity`.

Comment: u got to create activity by extends 
`Activity` class and then override its` onCreate()` method and put that code.. simple!

Comment: activity means screen in android .. so every UI must have activity.understand>?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782669/display-the-name-of-image-in-gallery-view    hey have you solution of this?  .please help.. if you know...